# Can I make my /home partition smaller and increase my / partition?

Tags: debian, partition

When I installed my OS I didn't set enough apace for my / partition.

```
Filesystem                      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
rootfs               9.2G  9.1G     0 100% /
udev                 10M     0   10M   0% /dev
tmpfs                 588M  888K  587M   1% /run
/dev/disk/by-uuid/87ea16ec-6ee7-42c4-8983-7d463a703f56  9.2G  9.1G     0 100% /
tmpfs                  5.0M     0  5.0M   0%        /run/lock
tmpfs                 3.6G   37M  3.5G   2% /run/shm
/dev/sda6             438G   32G  384G   8%           /home
/dev/sr0             5.8G  5.8G     0 100%         /media/cdrom0
/dev/sdb1            907G  773G  134G  86%            /media/1TB_
```

Can I safely resize them without losing everything, or am I out of luck?

Comment: If you are not using something like LVM, it would be possible but very hard to resize your partitions after using them. You might want to reinstall from scratch, or move your /var partition to /home/var and link /var to that location.

Answer (score 0):

First you should back up the data on / and /home.
Then use a [GParted LiveCD](http://gparted.org/livecd.php) to shrink the /home and grow the / partition.

When in doubt re-install and use a single partition for / and /home.